# INVALID_TICKET in Zoho mail php Integration

Tags: php, curl, zoho

I am using zoho email for sending email.
but when Trying the following code to send email ,
it returns the error `invalid_ticket`.

```
$data = array(

   "fromAddress"=> "from@gmail.com",
   "toAddress"=> "receive@gmail.com",
   "subject"=> "Email - Always and Forever",
   "content"=> "Email can never be dead. The most neutral and effective way, that can be used for one to many and two way communication.",
   "askReceipt" => "yes"
);


// Convert the PHP array into a JSON format

$payload = json_encode($data);

// Initialise new cURL session

$ch = curl_init('https://mail.zoho.in/api/accounts/<user_id>/messages');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',   
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($payload))
);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

print_r($result);
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Please help me to solve this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not the right forum for this question but according to official documentation, you need to `Kindly regenerate the authtoken with that generated authtoken which will work fine.`

Source: https://help.zoho.com/portal/en/community/topic/zoho-cretor-getting-error-message-invalid-ticket-id-code-4834-when-trying-to-insert-records-in-zoho-crm